# AppStore: are optional screenshots truly optionals? [Xcode]

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

As of Jan 2020, some device screenshots in `AppStore` are `optional`, such as **5.8 inch**, **4 inch**, **3.5 inch**, etc.

Are they truly optional, in the sense that, if an app doesn't provide screenshots for these devices, the app will get `ranked` lower when users searching from these devices?

Answer (score 1):

Good Question but yes they are truly optional. ranking is not base on screenshot. there are many more criteria  to it.